# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/lh5.googleusercontent.com/xyz.jpg (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

I am trying to get uri from the content resolver. But the file is not openeng. Its throwing an exception. Here is the code.

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    path = cursor.getString(idx); 
    File f = new File(path);    
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
```

The exception I am getting is

```
03-09 13:18:07.582: I/error(14693): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/lh5.googleusercontent.com/xyz.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Why is there a forward slash i.e. '/' at the beginning of the web address. Just test by removing it from the string first. Also, you should make null checks in your code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Here is a stack with the same problem and answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184540/getting-incorrect-file-path-for-some-images-in-android-android-one-device-or-w