# Getting Incorrect File Path For Some Images In Android ( Android One device or which allow to user save images into cloud)

Tags: android

I am trying to get the images from sd-card and displaying it into imageview. But My problem is that here some time I am getting correct path for some images but for some images, i am getting incorrect path.

This is my log:-

**correct path**

```
11-28 13:39:09.266: I/System.out(7950): filemangerstring = /external/images/media/2431
11-28 13:39:09.266: I/System.out(7950): selectedImagePath = /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2014-11-28-13-27-26.png
11-28 13:39:09.266: I/System.out(7950): filePathImage1 = /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2014-11-28-13-27-26.png
```

**incorrect path**

```
11-28 13:41:07.776: I/System.out(7950): filemangerstring = /0/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/ATCu2g0Tg_myGn8oBFbjtS_D4cYNTqUUnU2jBTDiz10=s0-d
11-28 13:41:07.776: I/System.out(7950): selectedImagePath = null
11-28 13:41:07.776: I/System.out(7950): filePathImage1 = /0/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/ATCu2g0Tg_myGn8oBFbjtS_D4cYNTqUUnU2jBTDiz10=s0-d
11-28 13:41:07.776: E/BitmapFactory(7950): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /0/https:/lh6.googleusercontent.com/ATCu2g0Tg_myGn8oBFbjtS_D4cYNTqUUnU2jBTDiz10=s0-d: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-28 13:41:07.776: E/BitmapFactory(7950): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /0/https:/lh6.googleusercontent.com/ATCu2g0Tg_myGn8oBFbjtS_D4cYNTqUUnU2jBTDiz10=s0-d: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-28 13:41:07.776: E/JHEAD(7950): can't open '/0/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/ATCu2g0Tg_myGn8oBFbjtS_D4cYNTqUUnU2jBTDiz10=s0-d'
```

**this is my function**

```
String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
}
```

**more code**

```
case R.id.cameraWallBtn:

        cameraBtn.setEnabled(false);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);

        fileName = n + ".jpg";

        String u = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/" + fileName;
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(u));
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Select Picture...");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                new Intent[] { i });

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FIRST_IMAGE);

        cameraBtn.setEnabled(true);

        break;

private String filePathImage1 = null;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {

    case FIRST_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.getData() != null)
                    selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                else
                    selectedImageUri = imageUri;
            } else
                selectedImageUri = imageUri;

            try {
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                System.out.println("filemangerstring = "+filemanagerstring);
                System.out.println("selectedImagePath = "+selectedImagePath);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePathImage1 = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePathImage1 = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                }

                System.out.println("filePathImage1 = "+filePathImage1);

                if (filePathImage1 != null) {

                    displayInImageViewAndRotateIfNeed(filePathImage1,
                            imagePreview);

                } else {
                    imagePreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Internal error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }

        break;
```

Comment: why `filemangerstring = /0/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/ATCu2g0Tg_myGn8oBFbjtS_D4cYNTqUUnU2jBTDiz10=s0-d`?? show what is `selectedImageUri` ?

Comment: You said you want them from sdcard. But that clearly is not from sd card. So please show more code. I think the mediastore not only displays from sdcard but also  from a drive in the cloud. Never seen that before. Very interesting.

Comment: @greenapps yes, I am using android one phone and my all images auto uploaded into google cloud. but this images also in my sdcard. I updated my code please have a look

Comment: Just skip those image paths from cloud. You will get the original image in the correct ones.

Comment: @greenapps I am sorry, is there any function for skip those image paths and get original images path?

Comment: Well that extra code shows that you you are not listing all images from sdcard as you stated. Instead you let the user pick one image displayed by the Gallery app.

Comment: yes I am allowing to user pick one image from gallery and display in imageview

Comment: As you are not listing the images (as i first thought) you cannot skip them. If the user has picked an image that you cannot handle you should use a Toast stating such. But better invoke the chooser in such a way that the Gallery app does not show them. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: What you have there is a https url. I think it leads directly to an image in the cloud. Copy that url to a browser and see it the browser can retrieve and display it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65818/discussion-between-rahul-rawat-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue will happen only **"android-one" phone or "the devices which allow to user to save the images into cloud"**. In this case, when we clicked on camera icon for selecting the images from the gallery. since some of the images may be uploaded in **Goolge_Cloud** and display us in gallery. there was difficulty to get the image path. because i was getting the image path from sdcard or internally memory and then uploading in our server. so i was getting the image url of google cloud like as

```
"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/dOx-Uo-m3bgjHgSQ8YpxUl8DHuqjoSdpYeK8OGAW8ac=s0-d"
```

when you will click on it, it will display the image which is in cloud.

so I fixed it like as

// if we will get the cloud url then

```
1)it will download it from cloud. ( a small loading bar will be displaying during download)
2)display in image view ( hide the loading bar once downloaded )
3)save temp into sdcard
4)take the path of this image 
5)upload it into server
6)remove this temp image which was saved into sdcard
```

**here is my code**

```
if (selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment().contains("https://lh5.googleusercontent.com"))
                    doDownloadTaskAndGetSaveImage(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
                else // do as you are doing
```

**some above steps task**

```
private void doDownloadTaskAndGetSaveImage(String lastPathSegment) {

    // show the progressBar.
    imgeLoadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //show the ImageView.
    imagePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    AQuery aq = new AQuery(imagePreview);
    aq.hardwareAccelerated11();
    aq.id(imagePreview).image(lastPathSegment, false, false, 0, 0,
            new BitmapAjaxCallback() {

                @Override
                public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm,
                        AjaxStatus status) {

                    System.out.println("url = " + url);

                    File file = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");

                    // delete exits image first.
                    System.out.println("file.exists() = " + file.exists());
                    if (file.exists())
                        file.delete();

                    // save this image into sdcard for temp.
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        boolean isSaved = bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,
                                75, fos);
                        if (isSaved) {
                            filePathImage1 = file.getPath();
                            System.out.println("get path = "
                                    + filePathImage1);
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        displayInImageViewAndRotateIfNeed(filePathImage1,
                                iv);

                        // hide the progressBar.
                        imgeLoadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });

}
```

**NOTE** I am using this library for downloading the image and getting callback. https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading